# How does Solidity deal with < 0.0001 ETH?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I have an ERC20 smart contract that allocates tokens to each user based on the amount of Ether it receives. I have added explicit checks to ensure any transaction with msg.value < the minimum token price are rejected.

My minimum token price is 1 finney. Now when I send an amount of 0.0001 to the smart contract. I expect the transaction to fail. However this doesn't seem to happen. Is this a bug with Solidity precision? Or am I doing something wrong?

My code is as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

import './TeamAllocation.sol';
import './UnsoldAllocation.sol';
import './zeppelin/SafeMath.sol';
import './zeppelin/token/StandardToken.sol';
import './zeppelin/ownership/Ownable.sol';

contract Token is StandardToken, Ownable {

    using SafeMath for uint;
    string public constant name = "SAMPLE";
    string public constant symbol = "SMP";
    uint public constant decimals = 18;

    TeamAllocation teamAllocation;
    UnsoldAllocation unsoldTokens;


    // Funding amount in Finney
    uint public constant tokenPrice  = 1 finney;

    // Multisigwallet where the proceeds will be stored.
    address public tokenFactory;
    // Multisigwallet to unsold tokens
    address public futureSale;

    // Sale Period
    uint public salePeriod;

    uint fundingStartBlock;
    uint fundingStopBlock;

    // flags whether ICO is afoot.
    bool fundingMode = true;

    //total used tokens
    uint totalUsedTokens;

    event Refund(address indexed _from,uint256 _value);
    event Migrate(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    modifier isNotFundable() {
        if (fundingMode) throw;
        _;
    }

    modifier isFundable() {
        if (!fundingMode) throw;
        _;
    }

    function Token(address _tokenFactory, uint256 _fundingStartBlock, uint256 _fundingStopBlock, address _icedWallet) {
      salePeriod = now.add(60 hours);
      tokenFactory = _tokenFactory;
      fundingStartBlock = _fundingStartBlock;
      fundingStopBlock = _fundingStopBlock;
      totalUsedTokens = 0;
      totalSupply = 800000000;
      futureSale = _icedWallet;
    }

    function pause() onlyOwner isFundable external returns (bool) {
      fundingMode = false;
    }

    function() payable isFundable external {
      if(now > salePeriod) throw;
      if(block.number < fundingStartBlock) throw;
      if(block.number > fundingStopBlock) throw;
      if(totalUsedTokens >= totalSupply) throw;

      if (msg.value < tokenPrice) throw;

      //transfer money to tokenFactory MultisigWallet
      if(!tokenFactory.send(msg.value)) throw;

      uint numTokens = msg.value.div(tokenPrice);
      totalUsedTokens = totalUsedTokens.add(numTokens);
      if (totalUsedTokens > totalSupply) throw;

      balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(numTokens);

      Transfer(0, msg.sender, numTokens);
    }


    //@notice Function that reports how long the sale is active
    function checkSalePeriod() external constant returns (uint) {
      return salePeriod;
    }

    //@notice Function that reports whether funding is active.
    function fundingActive() constant isFundable external returns (bool){
      if(block.number < fundingStartBlock || block.number > fundingStopBlock || totalUsedTokens > totalSupply){
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    //@notice Function reports the number of tokens available for sale
    function numberOfTokensLeft() constant returns (uint256) {
      if (block.number > fundingStopBlock) {
        return 0;
      }
      uint tokensAvailableForSale = totalSupply - totalUsedTokens;
      return tokensAvailableForSale;
    }

    function finalize() isFundable onlyOwner external {
      if ((block.number <= fundingStopBlock ||
        totalUsedTokens < minTokensForSale) &&
        totalUsedTokens < totalSupply) throw;

      if(futureSale == address(0)) throw;

        // switch funding mode off
        fundingMode = false;

        //Allot team tokens to a smart contract which will frozen for 9 months

        //transfer any balance available to Pillar Multisig Wallet
        if (!tokenFactory.send(this.balance)) throw;
    }

    function refund() isFundable external {
      if(block.number <= fundingStopBlock) throw;
      if(totalUsedTokens >= minTokensForSale) throw;

      uint plrValue = balances[msg.sender];
      if(plrValue == 0) throw;

      balances[msg.sender] = 0;

      uint ethValue = plrValue.mul(tokenPrice);
      if(!msg.sender.send(ethValue)) throw;
      Refund(msg.sender, ethValue);
    }
}
```

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Updated the question with full code. Deployed this contract and sent 0.0001 ether to it. I expect the contract to fail. But it doesn't!

Comment: Deployed contract on Rinkeby address: 0x256edad64ad7b0ddd2a6bd397bb248dcddcf2796, If I send anything less than 1 finney to this contract I expect the transaction to fail. But this doesn't seem to happen. https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xd1a1fbe2f094a90e94eebe04d5005518a5359297c711641dbde46881dee7c1e9

Comment: My understand is that msg.value will be reported in wei, while the tokenPrice is in finney. The comparisons should be valid anyway, won't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transaction is indeed throwing and working as expected. The issue is the blockchain explorer. Unfortunately etherscan is falsely reporting it as having succeeded.

Look here: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xd1a1fbe2f094a90e94eebe04d5005518a5359297c711641dbde46881dee7c1e9

You can in fact see that all gas was consumed by the transaction, which should probably only use a 100k at most. It is fair to presume from this that there was an exception. But let's have a closer look by opening the Geth DebugTrace offered by etherscan.

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xd1a1fbe2f094a90e94eebe04d5005518a5359297c711641dbde46881dee7c1e9

On the VM trace we indeed do see that the expected exception was encountered, and the exception occurs on the msg.value < tokenPrice check, so no need to worry.

Comment: Thanks. Ah, didn't foresee an error with Etherscan :-)